# How to get distinct row based on criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table with data like this

```
ID    | Desc | Status
------+------+------------
1     | abc  | Completed
1     | abc  | Completed
1     | def  | Planned
1     | def  | Planned
1     | ghi  | Rescheduled
1     | ghi  | Rescheduled
2     | abc  | Completed
2     | def  | Planned
2     | ghi  | Planned
```

I need to get one row for each ID based on Status. One row for `Planned` and for other, if an ID has both status `Completed` & `Rescheduled`, then `Rescheduled` row must be selected or else `Completed`

e.g.

ID 1 has `Planned`, `Completed` & `Rescheduled` status. The output should be as below

one row `Planned` for ID=1 & one row "Rescheduled" for ID=1

```
ID    | Desc | Status
------+------+------------
1     | ghi  | Rescheduled
1     | def  | Planned
2     | abc  | Completed
2     | def  | Planned
```

Comment: you need to group by of status and id

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text, not as as images. (No need to change here, but when you ask another question...)

Comment: I'd guess UNION can be used here.

Comment: If i do group_by ID and Status, then i will get 3 rows                                          1 abc Completed
1 def Planned
1 ghi Rescheduled  . But how to tell if ID has Completed and Rescheduled, then pick Rescheduled

Comment: @jarlh - i can do UNION for Planned, but issue is with Completed and Rescheduled for same ID

Comment: Your sample data should have duplicates to get count > 1, and a Completed only ID.

Comment: Did you try Join may be something like this `select * from table_name a where Status = 'planned' or Status = 'Rescheduled' 
FULL OUTER JOIN
(select * from table_name where Status = 'Completed') b
ON a.id = b.id`

Comment: Whyt does your `Count` result column mean? It always contains 1 even when there are two such rows in the table (i.e. two rows for `'ghi'/'Rescheduled'`, but `Count` is 1), so what do you count actually?

Comment: What if I have two rows with the same `Id` and `Status`, but different `Desc`? E.g. `1|abc|Planned` and `1|def|Planned`. Whould you show both rows in your result? Or only one? If only one, which?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - Count is always 1. That column i am using for Sum (its irrelevant in this case).    If i have different Desc, then it should give only one row

Comment: Then I must ask again: If only one, which? What rule do you want to apply to decide for a row? Which `Desc` schall be shown?

Comment: As to the downvotes your request got: I suppose this is because you haven't shown any effort to solve your problem yourself. You are supposed to come here with a concrete problem. You could have shown a query that gets you all desired 'Planned' and 'Completed' rows at least. Then your question would have been how to add 'Rescheduled' rows for the IDs without a 'Completed' entry. Instead your request reads "I want a query. Write it for me."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out using logic from @Krishna Muppalla and @Thorsten Kettner. Thanks you all for your suggestions.

```
select * from 
(
    select 
         distinct ID
        ,Desc
        ,Status
        ,max(Status) over (partition by ID, desc) as New_Status
    from tdata 
    where Status in ('Completed','Rescheduled')
) A
where A.Status = A.New_Status

UNION

select 
     distinct ID
    ,Desc
    ,Status
    ,max(Status) over (partition by ID, desc) as New_Status
from tdata 
where Status in ('Planned')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your can do it with `NOT EXISTS` and then return (as your expected output) the minimum value of `desc` for each combination of `id` and `status`:

```
select t.id, min(t.[desc]) [desc], t.status 
from tablename t
where status in ('Planned', 'Rescheduled')
or not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where id = t.id and status = 'Rescheduled'
)
group by t.id, t.status
order by t.id, t.status
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=42de9765b7ea8b717407fab229fbb6e3).
Results:

```
> id | desc | status     
> -: | :--- | :----------
>  1 | def  | Planned    
>  1 | ghi  | Rescheduled
>  2 | abc  | Completed  
>  2 | def  | Planned
```

Comment: And do a GROUP BY to get the count.

Comment: With this query, we will get Completed status also for Id 1

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
select id, desc, status, 1 count from(
select id, desc, status, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id) rownum from(
select distinct id, desc, status, 1 count
from tablename where status = 'Planned')  x ) y
where rownum = 1
union all
select id, desc, status, 1 from(
select id, desc, status, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id order by status desc) rownum from(
select distinct id, desc, status from tablename where status in ('Rescheduled','Completed')) x ) y
where rownum = 1
order by 1,2,3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CTE` to remove duplicate records, then apply `CASE WHEN THEN` to get desired results like :

```
WITH CTE_Result AS
(
  select distinct Id,description, status 
  from tdata
)
select Id,
CASE 
WHEN description='Planned' THEN 'Planned'
WHEN description='Planned'OR description='Rescheduled' AND (select Count(t.description) from tdata t where t.id=id)>1 THEN 'Rescheduled'
ELSE 'Completed'
END as description,
status
from CTE_Result;
```

Sample fiddle is http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/cb394/49

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the minimum status per ID, which is either `'Completed'` or not:

```
with data as
(
  select
    id, status, min([Desc]) as description, min(status) over (partition by id) as min_status
  from mytable
  group by id, status
)
select id, status, description
from data
where status in ('Planned', 'Completed') or min_status <> 'Completed'
order by id, status;
```